# Moving dotted border using CSS

Tags: css, border

I have class that applies a dotted style border property to a text block at runtime. I am  trying to find a solution, using CSS, that makes the border move like a gif image.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @Jeremy Battle: BoltClock is a clock. He simply moved forward in time, read the comment you posted, came back and posted it before you did.

Comment: @Radek S: That has to be the best comment about me that I have ever read, thank you.

Comment: Actually not such a terrible idea if you want to give the effect of marching ants as in a Photoshop selection area.

Comment: I think it's funny how many people have said you shouldn't do this. I'm pretty sure your question was about "how", not about "whether or not".

Comment: @jag2007: yes, right my view was how it should be done.

Comment: +1 Please... do. I can see situations where this will add good user experience (try finding a time when creating an event on Google Calendar).

Comment: This is one method - http://codepen.io/techniq/pen/gzyHI

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This depends on what exactly you want the animation to look like.

In general, the styles given to you by `border-style` are rendered statically; it's simply not possible to animate them.

Even with CSS3, your options are fairly limited. The best you can do with `border-image` is either with a carefully-crafted animated GIF (again, it would depend on how a browser implements `border-image` with animated images), or with a gradient animation — and whichever you choose depends on browser compatibility and how you want your effect to look.

Otherwise you can experiment with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to achieve your desired effect.

As a word of warning, though, unless you can ensure your animation meets the relevant WCAG guidelines, in particular 2.2.2 and 2.3, I strongly advise against especially going for the animated-GIF look. On top of being dangerous to certain people, a poorly-crafted animation may turn out more annoying than helpful to most — this is what made animated GIFs so infamous back in the day.

In other words, use this technique sparingly, and only when you know it adds to the user experience rather than taking away from it.

Comment: You could suggest him use `blink` tags, what more does anyone want :)

Comment: @Myles Gray You haven't even seen what graphics he wants to implement - how can you say it will look ugly? He might find a perfectly reasonable solution.

Comment: Yup - only way to achieve this is with an animated .gif (2px black white that alternates it's colors) set as the border-image.

Comment: @Maarten: It would be annoying, either for vendors to implement (unless you're *transitioning* then it's already done) or for users to look at.

Comment: I know I'm late to this party, but wow is there a lot of arrogance here.  I can think of at least one good use for an animated border property that would be unobtrusive, attractive, and useful - using the bottom border as a progress indicator on a save button.  I'm sure there are many, many others as well.  How about you focus on answering the question being asked instead of crapping all over the idea, especially when you have no idea what the use case he's addressing is?

Comment: @Isochronous: You know what, you're right. I was extremely cynical when I wrote the original answer - and I imagine so was everyone who upvoted it. While I still don't trust half the people reading this to not go and make gratuitous blinking effects the least I could do now is caution the reader against doing so.

Answer (score 28):

Not CSS3, but it works: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/animated-photoshop-selection-on-a-web-page

You can make it without images, by utlizing CSS3 gradients for the stripes and animating background-position (rough demo: http://codepen.io/christopheschwyzer/pen/CEwBI), but I wouldn't recommend it since it would only work well on Webkit.

Comment: Demo link is broken.

Answer (score 18):

I've made a [complete example](http://cssdesk.com/aeBpr) based on [this article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/animated-photoshop-selection-on-a-web-page). Enjoy!

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-image: url(http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/selection.gif);
  
  border: 1px solid;
}

.selected {
  border: 0px;
}

.inner {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  background-color: #9CF;
}

.selected .inner {
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer selected">
  <div class="inner" />
</div>
```

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a pretty flexible SCSS option:

```
$antlength: 50px;
$antwidth: 10px;
$antcolor: black;

@keyframes marching-ants {
    0%   {background-position: 0 0, $antlength 100%, 0 $antlength, 100% 0;}
    100% {background-position: $antlength 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% $antlength;}
}

.ants {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $antcolor 50%, transparent 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, $antcolor 50%, transparent 50%),
        linear-gradient(0, $antcolor 50%, transparent 50%),
        linear-gradient(0, $antcolor 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
    background-size: $antlength $antwidth, $antlength $antwidth, $antwidth $antlength, $antwidth $antlength;
    animation: marching-ants 400ms infinite linear;
}
```

Collapsed to a snippet:

```css
@keyframes marching-ants {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 50px 100%, 0 50px, 100% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50px 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 50px;
  }
}

.ants {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0, black 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 50px 10px, 50px 10px, 10px 50px, 10px 50px;
  animation: marching-ants 400ms infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="ants">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j3epnurd/

Comment: Thanks @SAMPro I added as a snippet now too

Comment: This answer deserves more vote than selected answer!

Answer (score 3):

I'm also looking for such a solution since I'm trying to simulate the animated border that excel uses to indicate that the current selection has been cut and is waiting to be pasted.

Tacky? No, not in the context of the use I intend.

I found this jQuery plugin.  http://there4development.com/projects/animatedborder/, the orginal poster might want to give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two examples using `border-image`.

**Advantages :**

- Only one div
- Inside can be truly transparent

```css
.selected {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border-image-outset: 0px;
  border-image-repeat: repeat;
  border-image-source: url("http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/selection-big.gif");
}

.v1 {
  left: 100px;

  border-image-slice: 6;
  border-image-width: 1px;
}

.v2 {
  left: 300px;

  border-image-slice: 3;
  border-image-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: #aaa;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam metus hendrerit venenatis placerat. Morbi sem ex, egestas at egestas iaculis, imperdiet in mauris. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam eu porttitor libero, vel porta ipsum. Proin egestas consequat urna, et rhoncus arcu congue vitae. Maecenas at massa mollis, accumsan mauris in, faucibus ligula. Nulla sed lorem pharetra lacus dictum lobortis sit amet id tellus. Vestibulum porta auctor maximus. Fusce congue, orci et feugiat ultricies, turpis mi egestas est, nec vulputate nulla risus quis lorem. Sed vitae risus rhoncus, ultricies nunc non, mollis mauris.</p>

<div class="selected v1">
</div>

<div class="selected v2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to animate the dotted border?

You could look into [CSS 3 border images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images), which would allow you to provide an (animated) gif for your border, if you don't mind not supporting IE.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a gif image in the background, the only solution for doing it via css. otherwise your javascript