# How to make a moving dashed border with CSS?

Tags: java, css

I'm displaying a dashed border around an input text element with:
`border: 1px dashed black`;

Can I somehow define an "offset" to tell the browser where to start with the border?

My goal is to define a timer, and alter the offset of the dashed border (using java GWT element.setAttribute()), so that the simulation of a clockwise-moving dashed border results.

Is there any existing offset for borders with css?

Comment: CSS doesn't directly support this. Search for `css marching ants  border` and/or see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_ants Or you could use both `outline` and `border` and combine them somehow.

Comment: Its impossible, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261122/moving-dotted-border-using-css

Comment: Would it be ok to use border-image ?

Comment: Hm border image would be static, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a somewhat convoluted workaround to achieve a similar effect using an animated .gif as the background of a div, with whatever content you wanted "bordered" placed in a second div  nested within the first with a 1px margin.

The animated .gif should be a small square (8px x 8px) with 3px-wide diagonal lines moving across it from left to right (you can adjust the sizes to adjust the width of the lines).  When only a pixel's width or height of this image is visible, it appears to be a moving dashed border.

This technique is detailed here by Matthew Taylor at his blog: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/animated-photoshop-selection-on-a-web-page.