# css border hover animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to hover border animation. But i am not getting animation,

Here is the my code. Can you please help me.

```
$(".divBox1").mouseover(function(){
        console.log('enter');
        $(this).animate({border: "3px solid #000"}, 100);
    }).mouseout(function(){
            console.log('out');
            $(this).animate({border: "3px solid #FFF55B"}, 100);
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery properly installed into your webpage? Showing us how you did that could have some effect on the answers you may receive.

Comment: is your code already inner `$(document).ready(function(){ });` ?

Comment: 'code'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.1.228/n70/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('.divBox1').on('click', function(){
  $('.divBox1').removeClass('BorderBox');
  $(this).addClass('BorderBox');
 });
 $(".divBox1").mouseover(function(){
    //console.log('enter');
    $(this).animate({"border": "3px solid #000"}, 100);
}).mouseout(function(){
    //console.log('out');
    $(this).animate({"border": "3px solid #FFF55B"}, 100);
});
});
</script>'code'

Comment: @sridhar you need to use `jQuery ui` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ,add quotation mark to border property

```
$(".divBox1").mouseover(function(){
    //console.log('enter');
    $(this).animate({"border": "3px solid #000"}, 100);
}).mouseout(function(){
    //console.log('out');
    $(this).animate({"border": "3px solid #FFF55B"}, 100);
});
```

Comment: You have to make use of jquery-UI in order to animate the border-color

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing the css border properties in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

try it with css its easy

```
  .divBox1{
 border: 3px solid #FFF55B;
}

.divBox1:hover {
        border: 3px solid #000;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot animate static borders like this. U could manipulate with border-images in css3.

[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261122/moving-dotted-border-using-css) for more queries

Also have a look at this [plugin](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/animated-photoshop-selection-on-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

See you have to use `jQuery` and `jQuery ui` both for `animating colors`. Because your code suggests that `you just want to animate colors not the width`, animating width can be achieved with

`borderWidth: '3px'`

### css:

```css
.divBox1 {
   border:solid 3px #FFF55B;
}
```

### Script:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(function(){
         $(".divBox1").mouseover(function () {
             $(this).animate({borderColor: "#000"}, 800);
         }).mouseout(function () {
             $(this).animate({borderColor: "#FFF55B"}, 800);
         });
     });
 </script>
```

[**tryout in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvwmr/)

### Note:

Without `jquery ui` this won't work at all.

Comment: @sridhar now you can accept it as an answer to your quesion Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Unex_web_o/RMMpM/1/) what you want ?

```
    $(".divBox1").css("border","3px solid transparent").mouseover(function(){
        //console.log('enter');
        $(this).animate({"border-color": '#000'}, 100);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        //console.log('out');
        $(this).animate({"border-color": "#FFF55B"}, 100);
    });
```

## Note:

you need jQuery UI