# Spinning Effect Anchor tag CSS3

Tags: html, css

Helo Guys!

I was trying to create a spinning hover effect with CSS3.

Just made a circle spinning effect. Check the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/63yyeezn/26/

However what I want to do now is to create something tthat spins but this time its box type

just like this image:

[image]

So basically I want similar effect just like the jsFiddle I shown above however this time it must be box.

Really having a hard time figuring this out. Here's my CSS:

```
    body {
    background: #292929;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.twist {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
}
.twist:after {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content:'';
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.twist:before {
    speak: none;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}



 .twist.demo-4 {
    width: 92px;
    height: 92px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.twist.demo-4:before {
    line-height: 92px;
}
.twist.demo-4:after {
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 4px dashed #fff;
}
.twist.demo-4:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: #fff;
}
.twist.demo-4:hover i {
    color: #fff;
}

 .twist.demo-4.spin:hover {
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}
.twist.demo-4.spin:hover:after {
    -webkit-animation: spinAround 9s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spinAround 9s linear infinite;
    animation: spinAround 9s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinAround {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinAround {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spinAround {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me with a jsFiddle file.

Thanks!

Comment: Doubtful you could do this with CSS **except** in SVG _ http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261122/moving-dotted-border-using-css). Particularly [Lea Verou's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5270349/2007837)

Comment: Are there any out there who knows how to do this in PLAIN CSS3? It would be helpful to all of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer won't fit exactly your example, but may interest you as it's a full-CSS3 solution, without HTML markup change. The animation won't be a rotation, but a translation.

*Webkit version*

```css
.bordered {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bordered:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; /* 5px: border width */
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.bordered:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  bottom: -50%;
  background: black;
  z-index: -2;
}
.bordered:hover:after {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 50%, black 50%); /* black: border color*/
  background-size: 20px 100%; /* 20px: dash width */
  -webkit-animation: borderAnimated 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes borderAnimated {
  from {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20px, 0);
  }
}

/* --- Style only--- */
.bordered {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

The trick is to have a stripped background in the `:after` pseudo-element, and a fake empty background in the `:before` element, which will work as a mask. When hovering your element, you just have to animate the `:after` pseudo-element to get something nice.

Answer (score 3):

> Credits: [@vsynz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261122/moving-dotted-border-using-css/comment-38028914#comment38028914_5261122)

I don't think it can be possible only with static borders. Here is an alternative solution:

```css
.rotating-dashed {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #268;
}
.rotating-dashed .dashing {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.rotating-dashed .dashing:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.rotating-dashed .dashing:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.rotating-dashed .dashing:nth-of-type(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.rotating-dashed .dashing i {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid
}
.rotating-dashed strong {
    display: block;
    width: 105%;
    line-height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
.rotating-dashed:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rotating-dashed:hover .dashing i {
    -webkit-animation: slideDash 2.5s infinite linear;
    border-bottom: 5px dashed
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideDash {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating-dashed"> <span class="dashing"><i></i></span>
 <span class="dashing"><i></i></span>
 <span class="dashing"><i></i></span>
 <span class="dashing"><i></i></span>
 <strong>Demo</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however the demo you showed me is not moving at all when I hovered it. Also there must be a solid border on the normal state and a moving dashed border on a hover state.

Comment: This demo works in IE only. If you are trying to browse it in Chrome, you must change the animation properties into webkit. I'll prepare an example for you.

Comment: You should mention that you are using @vsync 's solution which he posted in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261122/moving-dotted-border-using-css/comment-38028914

Comment: @Danield actually it is a modified version of this: http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/zm7Et/

Comment: @Danield couldn't agreed more

Comment: @dippas actually it is 'desendaro's solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to just use padding here: .rotating-dashed {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #268;
} instead of width and height?

Comment: Padding is something different than height and width. If you think this is the answer, then mark as answer please.

Comment: Actually it is [desandro](http://jsfiddle.net/user/desandro/)'s [code](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/zm7Et). Possible wrong edit since vsynz and desandro are different persons. I am tired of that! Be happy in your sandbox.