# How to animate box border dotted on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I need to animate the border on hover.

Initially the box border will be hidden, once we hover the box, that time that border dotted will animate one by one fast.

```css
 .arrow{
    height: 172px;
        right: 12px;
        width: 140px;
        border-right: 2px dotted #2fb89a;
        border-bottom: 2px dotted #2fb89a;
        top: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: You mean you want each side of the border appearing one by one?

Comment: yes. bottom and right side animation

Comment: animation start from bottom and end with top

Comment: Do you really want to do it with css, or is it okay with image? Or you can refer this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261122/moving-dotted-border-using-css)

Comment: kindly need in css on hover option

Comment: Do you need something like this as a solution ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365839/dashed-border-animation-in-css3-animation?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @user3613129 not working actually

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the JS event `mouseover`.
Create a css class that does what you want, and on that event add/remove the class.

First, let's add an id to your div.

Then, this is how the event should look like:

```
document.getElementById("arrow").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
   event.target.classList.add("mystyle");
});
```

Now, you want to remove that border from the div when the "hover is over" so we need to remove the class on `mouseleave` event:

```
document.getElementById("arrow").addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){
   event.target.classList.remove("mystyle");
});
```

This is a quick, raw version of the code. You can polish it and make it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with only pseudoelements and :hover in CSS:

```
 .arrow{
    position:relative;
    height: 172px;
    right: 12px;
    width: 140px;
    top: 5px;
    }

.arrow::after,
.arrow::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    transition: all 2s;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;      
}

.arrow::after{
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #2fb89a;
    width: 0;
}

.arrow::before{
    border-right: 2px dotted #2fb89a;
    height: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);  
}

.arrow:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.arrow:hover::before{
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

You can see the results here.

https://codepen.io/ChemaAlfonso/pen/LvpKMV

Hope it helps you.